# create a new calculated table having top funded categories each year

Tags: powerbi, dax, top-n

A table contains 3 columns namely Year, Category and Amount in which the year and amount is a calculated column.

Table 1:

```
+------+----------+--------+
| Year | Category | amount |  
+------+----------+--------+
| 2016 | A        |     50 |  
| 2017 | B        |     85 |  
| 2015 | A        |     90 |  
| 2017 | C        |    135 |  
| 2016 | C        |     55 |  
| 2015 | B        |    180 |  
| 2017 | A        |     30 |  
| 2016 | B        |     45 |  
| 2015 | C        |     60 |  
+------+----------+--------+
```

now I need to create a new table with top 2 rows having highest amount in each year using DAX i.e an output like below given table

```
+------+----------+--------+
| Year | Category | amount |
+------+----------+--------+
| 2015 | B        |    180 |
|      | A        |     90 |
| 2016 | c        |     55 |
|      | A        |     50 |
| 2017 | C        |    135 |
|      | B        |     85 |
+------+----------+--------+
```

My DAX:

```
New Table = CALCULATE(TOPN(3, 'Table 1', 'Table 1'[Amount],DESC),ALLEXCEPT('Table 1','Table 1'[Year]))
```

but I'm getting error. So can anyone suggest me the correct DAX to proceed with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Rank` column with the following DAX:

```
Rank = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        'Table 1',
        'Table 1'[Year] = EARLIER('Table 1'[Year]) &&
        'Table 1'[Amount] > EARLIER('Table 1'[Amount])
    )
) + 1
```

Then you can filter the table where `Rank` is less than or equal to 2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but It is hitting an error like  "The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value."

Comment: @SharaniRajasekaran Are you creating a new `Column` instead of `Measure` or `Table`? Can you post a screenshot or so?

Comment: Sorry,  I gave your dax including the +1 that is why I was getting an error. Just now I noticed it. Thank u I got the expected result

Comment: @SharaniRajasekaran Glad to help!